# Error al abrir modal con dateClick (No muestra nada)

Tags: javascript, laravel, fullcalendar

Estoy intentando crear un evento en un día especifico de Full calendar, el modal funciona bien si se abre desde una  pero al intentar abrirlo con javascript no hace nada.
los archivos que estoy utilizando son los siguientes.
Aqui es donde aparece el calendario y por ende el modal.

```
     @extends('layouts.app')
     @section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div id="agenda">
      Calendario
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#evento">
  Launch
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="evento" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modelTitleId" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            
     <form action="">

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="id">ID</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" id="" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="">
  <small id="helpId" class="form-text text-muted">Help text</small>
</div>

   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="title">Titulo</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Escribe el titulo del evento">
     <small id="helpId" class="form-text text-muted">Help text</small>
   </div> 
   
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="descripcion">Descripcion</label>
     <textarea class="form-control" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" rows="3"></textarea>
   </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="start">start</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="start" id="start" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="">
  <small id="helpId" class="form-text text-muted">Help text</small>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="end">end</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="end" id="end" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="">
  <small id="helpId" class="form-text text-muted">Help text</small>
</div>

</form>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

El siguiente fracmento pertenece al archivo app.blade.php el cual es el archivo principal, donde se colocan los scripts

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/locales-all.js"></script>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            @if (Route::has('login'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif

                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
<script src="{{ asset('js/agenda.js') }}" defer></script>
        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

A continuacion se presenta el script, el cual me esta generando el problema, particularmente en la funcion  DateClick, eh pensado que se debe a la version que estoy manejando sin embargo no encuentro alguna respuesta solida.

```
      <script>
     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     var calendarEl = document.getElementById('agenda');
     var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      locale:"es",

      headerToolbar:{
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,listWeek'
      },

     dateClick:function(info){
        $("#evento").modal("show");
     }

    });
    calendar.render();
  });
  </script>
```

al ingresar a inspeccionar las lineas de codigo me marca un error como el siguiente:
agenda.js:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at t.dateClick (agenda.js:17:13)

Comment: El tema es... ¿tu app tiene cargado JQuery?

Comment: Tenias razón, el punto es que no sabia muy bien como integrar jquery en mi proyecto laravel, pero solo basto con integrar el script en el archivo app.blade.php y ya funciona correctamente

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Agregar Jquery app.blade.php

< script >

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js">

< / script>

lo recalco porque no se nota la respuesta
en los comentarios , a mi también me ayudo agregandolo